Is it possible to write protect a xlsx file from R?
I do not want collaborators to make changes in Excel files I export from R.
Actually I export them using writexl::write_xlsx() or sometimes WriteXLS::WriteXLS() functions and afterwards I have to open the file and write-protect it manually.
Is there any function able to write directly a readonly Excel file?
I know the xlsx::write.xlsx() function has a password parameter, but it blocks the reading of the file. I need it readable but not writable.
Thanks in advance.

The openxlsx2 package can implement the normal workbook and sheet protection functions Excel offers.
library(openxlsx2)
wb <- wb_workbook()
wb$add_worksheet("S1")
wb$add_data_table(1, x = iris[1:30, ])

wb$protect_worksheet(
  "S1",
  protect = TRUE,
  properties = c("formatCells", "formatColumns", "insertColumns", "deleteColumns")
)

wb_protect(wb, protect = TRUE, password = "Password", lock_structure = TRUE)

See

https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/openxlsx2/html/wb_protect.html
https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/openxlsx2/html/wb_protect_worksheet.html


I did not know about the existence of openxlsx2. The same is possible with the regular openxlsx: https://rdrr.io/cran/openxlsx/man/protectWorkbook.html

It's worth looking at, it's under very active development and able to do a fair few things that openxlsx struggles with.

Thank you @Nick. I did not know this interesting package. Easy to install (not all writing xlsx packages are) and fast.
Your code misses how to save the protected xlsx. I simplified and completed your example:
library(openxlsx2)
wb <- wb_workbook()
wb$add_worksheet("S1")
wb$add_data_table(1, x = iris[1:30, ])
wb$protect_worksheet("S1", protect = TRUE)
wb$save("setosa.xlsx")

